# How to write 3 address code for a recursive function?

Tags: compiler-construction

I have read example of writing 3 address codes for various conditional and iterative statements but today I found a question asking to write 3 address codes for a recursive implementation of factorial function.

```cpp
int fact(int n) {
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    return n * fact(n-1);
}
```

How can we write 3 address codes for such functions?

Comment: How would you write it if the recursive call was not that but a call to some other function? I don't think recursion makes it different.

Comment: Can you briefly explain or point me to some resource on how to express function calls in 3 address codes?